# Java buffered writer wont write all data

Tags: java, for-loop, bufferedwriter

```
public static void save() 
{
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try 
    {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Gdx.files.external(file).write(false)));
        out.write(Double.toString(FinanceSystem.currentPlayerCash));
        out.write("\n");
        out.write(Integer.toString(DateSystem.day));
        out.write("\n");
        out.write(Integer.toString(DateSystem.month));
        out.write("\n");
        out.write(Integer.toString(DateSystem.year));
        out.write("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i <= InventorySystem.drugsOwned.size(); i++)
            out.write(Integer.toString(InventorySystem.drugsOwned.get(i))+"\n");
        for(int i = 0; i <= AttributeSystem.attributeNames.length; i++)
            out.write(Integer.toString(AttributeSystem.attributeValues.get(i)) + "\n");



    } 
    catch (Throwable e) {} 
    finally 
    {
       try
       {
          if (out != null)
               out.close();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) {}
    }
```

My problem is that after the for loop for the inventory system.drugsowned nothing else gets wrote to file. So in this example AttributeSystem.attributeValues doesnt get wrote.  I have also tried putting other things to be wrote after this loop including non loop things and they also haven't wrote. Whagwaan?

Comment: Maybe it's throwing an exception, which you're completely ignoring as if it didn't happen? Don't do that...

Comment: You should put some logging in the exception blocks. Probably there were some exceptions thrown before/during writing the attributes.

Comment: Empty catch block! Mother of all mysteries!

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= InventorySystem.drugsOwned.size(); i++)
    out.write(Integer.toString(InventorySystem.drugsOwned.get(i))+"\n");
```

The `<=` should be a `<`. So if there are 5 items in the collection, you're asking for element 5, which is the *6th* element as the index is 0-based. That will throw an exception.

That's then getting masked by this:

```
catch (Throwable e)
{
}
```

You're completely hosing yourself here in terms of diagnostics:

- Unless you can really handle an exception, don't catch it - or catch it and then rethrow it after logging (or whatever)
- Catch *specific* exceptions wherever you can. (Catching `Exception` is bad; catching `Throwable` is worse.)
- Silently catching *without even logging* is a terrible idea. That means you have *no idea* how often you've got problems, or what they were.

(Additionally, the code suggests you're either overusing static variables, or you need to sort out your naming conventions. That's a different matter though.)

Comment: "You are completely hosing yourself" is right on the money.  Empty catch block is almost always incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for quick and useful response. To be honest i only have a vague idea of how try/catch blocks work, so ill take your advice and rework it. Should i just remove the try/catch entirely?

Comment: @Jon. Can you modify language in a first bullet. I think you've meant to say "don't catch it - rethrow it". Otherwise, a really nice exception handling tutorial in 3 lines :).

Comment: Also with the static variable thing yeh i am using loads of those, what's the problem with using them?

Comment: @andy07070: They're basically global variables, leading to poor object orientation, poor testability, concurrency nightmares etc...